# Record my animation and upload it to my server

Tags: video, record, movie, mpeg

I write some flash animation application that user can customate.
I wont to record the animation inside the flash and send it to my java server - prefer in mpeg.

In short, the idea is record some event in my flah game and the outcome will be some video/movie in my server side...

I will happy for 
Any help, idea wil...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a program which emulated how a web browser talks to a (Netscape style) plugin. Then this "browser" loaded the Adobe Flash plugin, drove it frame by frame.

I used Linux, so I could "just" read the X11 buffer of the plugin (got it via GTK I think) and save each frame as a PNG.  Then I converted each PNG to mpeg.

The hard part was deciding when the animation was complete. Many flash files do not have a "quit" or "done" command, they just loop.

Also, for some reason it took a while for the plugin to begin displaying animation, so the first 10-12 frames would have to be checked and discarded.